# How to use numpy.argmax to extract values from three-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a three-dimensional numpy array, the index of the maximum value across the first dimension (axis 0) can be calculated using `numpy.argmax`.

How do I use the result of `argmax` to extract the said maximum values from another array with a similar shape?

For example, given the following:

```
import numpy as np

ndarr1 = np.round(np.random.rand(4, 2, 3), 2)
ndarr2 = np.round(np.random.rand(4, 2, 3), 2)
argmax1 = np.argmax(ndarr1, axis=0)

ndarr1
# array([[[0.89, 0.79, 0.64],
#         [0.03, 0.53, 0.1 ]],
#
#        [[0.21, 0.76, 0.99],
#         [0.47, 0.08, 0.48]],
#
#        [[0.67, 0.94, 0.99],
#         [0.98, 0.75, 0.59]],
#
#        [[0.09, 0.96, 0.98],
#         [0.43, 0.98, 0.71]]])

argmax1
# array([[0, 3, 1],
#        [2, 3, 3]], dtype=int64)

ndarr2
# array([[[0.79, 0.72, 0.82],
#         [0.25, 0.7 , 0.56]],
#
#        [[0.46, 0.11, 0.31],
#         [0.55, 0.76, 0.13]],
#
#        [[0.09, 0.23, 0.35],
#         [0.3 , 0.42, 0.06]],
#
#        [[0.24, 0.1 , 0.92],
#         [0.82, 0.52, 0.7 ]]])
```

What function do I call to obtain the following array derived from retrieving items using `argmax1` from `ndarr2`:

```
# array([[0.79, 0.1 , 0.31],
#        [0.3 , 0.52, 0.7 ]])
```

Note that I cannot use `numpy.amax` because I need to use the `argmax` results to extract values from a different array which has the same shape as `ndarr1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), you can use `np.take_along_axis` after expanding the dimension of `argmax1`.

```py
max2 = np.take_along_axis(ndarr2, np.expand_dims(argmax1, axis=0), axis=0)
print(max2)
# [[[0.79 0.1  0.31]
#   [0.3  0.52 0.7 ]]]
```

You can avoid the manual dimension expansion if you had instead set `keepdims=True` when creating `argmax1`, i.e.

```py
argmax1 = np.argmax(ndarr1, axis=0, keepdims=True)
max2 = np.take_along_axis(ndarr2, argmax1, axis=0)
```

Comment: **Note to others using this method:** The result is a tuple with the same number of dimensions as `ndarr2` but with only one element on the first axis (if `axis=0`). For example `max2.shape` is `(1, 2, 3)`. If the intention of using `np.argmax` was to flatten the input array and eliminate one dimension, then, you must remove the extra dimension that was added. In my case, the final code was something like this `max2 = np.take_along_axis(ndarr2, np.expand_dims(argmax1, axis=0), axis=0)[0]` which yielded a two-dimensional array with shape `(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b = np.ogrid[0:2, 0:3] # 2nd and 3rd dimensions of the array
ndarray2[argmax1, a, b]
```

If you want a one-liner:

```
ndarray2[argmax1, *np.ogrid[0:2, 0:3]]
```

---

Answering question below.  If the array's shape is (A, B, C, D), then you could write:

```
ndarray2[argmaz1, *np.ogrid[:B, :C, :D])
```

(The `0:` is unnecessary and could have been left out. This for anything with three or more dimensions.

Because of a fluke in the definition of `ogrid`, if the original array only has two dimensions, you leave out the `*`.  `ogrid` with a single slice argument returns an array rather than a singleton list of arrays.

If you have an array and you don't know its size or dimensions, you'll just have to build the slices by hand:

```
slices = [slice(0, i) for i in ndarray2.shape[1:]]
grid = np.ogrid[*slices]
if len(slices) == 1:  # make array into singleton list
    grid = [grid]
ndarray2[argmax1, *grid]
```

Comment: If it is possible to make this method work with input arrays of an arbitrary number of dimensions (i.e. 2 and above), kindly update the code tho show how it can be done. Thanks.